# How to assign data from Cloud Firestore to a global variable for Android

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use `docRef.get()` to get a Map of a collection from the Cloud Firestore. However, I cannot use the value in the map after I leave `public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot)` method. In JS, I know I can do a `subscribe` method but in Android I don't know what to do.

This is my code to get the Map:

```
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                    doc = documentSnapshot.getData();
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,"Data loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,"No data exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("TAG",e.toString());
            }
        });
```

And I want to use the Map after that, to set the `textView` to be the `message`:

```
for(String key : doc.keySet()){
    message += key + "\n" + doc.get(key)+"\n";
} 
ui.setText(message);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value

Answer (score 1):

As @a_local_nobody points, `Firestore` calls are `Asynchronous` and you could use a `callback` to trigger when you have downloaded that data and this are disponible.
Your `doc` variable have this data disponible once the `onSuccess` callback are executed but maybe other part of your code use it before `onSuccess` are called (Async).

Another approach would be to wrap your code into a method and use them inside the onSuccess principal callback, so you are sure this method will execute when the data get disponible and you don't need an extra interface to use it as callback:

```
public void setMessagesToUi(Doc doc){
for(String key : doc.keySet()){
    message += key + "\n" + doc.get(key)+"\n";
} 
ui.setText(message);
}
```

And then use it:

```
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                    setMessagesToUi(documentSnapshot.getData());
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,"Data loaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this,"No data exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("TAG",e.toString());
            }
        });
```